# What are the limitations of an iPhone that prevent one from creating a nds emulator on it?

Tags: iphone, emulation

I've read that there are too many buttons that are required for playing most games that the iPhone cannot accommodate for. Additionally, is the even iPhone powerful enough for a DS emulator? Thanks.

This contains some info on the topic but its not very comprehensive. http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-267942.html

Answer (score 2):

Whether it's powerful enough or not isn't really relevant - Apple's app store terms prohibit emulators:

> 3.3.2 An Application may not itself install or launch other executable
>   code by any means, including without
>   limitation through the use of a
>   plug-in architecture, calling other
>   frameworks, other APIs or otherwise.
>   No interpreted code may be downloaded
>   or used in an Application except for
>   code that is interpreted and run by
>   Apple's Documented APIs and builtin
>   interpreter(s).

Comment: I am talking about the technical limitations. There are many emulators available for download from Cydia.